# Pass a variable to several sequenced functions in IO

Tags: haskell

There are a bunch of IO computations whose result don't matter, and that rely on a same context variable. I would like an aesthetical way to pass this argument to all functions.

Say that I want to print a char several times

```
c = 'c'
main = do
  putChar c
  putChar c
  putChar c
```

but I don't want to write the parameter each time.

The following works just fine:

```
samearg :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (a -> m ()) -> a -> m ()
samearg fs ctx = foldl (\d f -> d >>= \_ -> f ctx) (return ()) fs
(>^=) = flip samearg

'c' >^= [putChar,putChar,putChar]
```

Now, I'm just curious whether I could have written things according to my initial idea, or whether there is some standard way to do this. I wanted to write something like `'c' >^= putChar >^= putChar >^= putChar` that would reduce to this

```
((return 'c' >>= putChar >>= \_ -> return 'c')
>>= putChar >>= \_ -> return 'c')
>>= putChar
```

but this operator I wrote isn't reducing to what I expected

```
(>^=) :: Monad m => m b -> (b -> m a) -> m b
(>^=) ctx f = ctx >>= f >>= \_ -> ctx

return 'c' >^= putChar >^= putChar >^= putChar
```

which I understand, but I'm still wondering whether I could have made it work.

Comment: What do you think of `replicateM_ 3 (putChar c)` or is `putChar` a placeholder?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem rich enough to explain what you're really trying to accomplish. Could you give a more complicated one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This makes the possibly too-optimistic assumption that all the functions have a return type of `IO ()`.)

---

`putChar` has type `Char -> IO ()`. There are three types here, all of which have `Monoid` instances:

- (Since `base-4.9`) `() <> () == ()`
- (Since `base-4.10`) If `b` is a monoid, then `IO b` is as well; `m1 <> m2 == (liftA2 (<>)) m1 m2` (a new `IO` action, in which the results of executing the original `IO` actions are combined, is returned).
- (Since `base-4.9`) If `b` is a monoid, then for `f,g :: a -> b` we have `f <> g == \x -> f x <> g x` (both functions are called on the same argument and the return values are combined.

Putting this all together, functions of type `Char -> IO ()` form a monoid.

```
> :t putChar <> putChar <> putChar
putChar <> putChar <> putChar :: Char -> IO ()
> (putChar <> putChar <> putChar) 'c'
ccc>
```

So you can simply write

```
main = putChar <> putChar <> putChar $ c
```

or

```
main = mconcat (replicate 3 putChar) $ c
```

Comment: Or another: `main = stimes 3 putChar c`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fixed version of `(>^=)`

```
(>^=) :: Monad m => m b -> (b -> m a) -> m b
(>^=) ctx f = ctx >>= \y -> f y >> return y   -- only uses ctx once
```

You can also put the actions in a list and traverse it, using existing combinators:

```
traverse_ (\go -> go 'c') [putChar, putChar, putChar]
```